# The verb for initiating an intimacy but waiting for consent

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a verb to fill in this sentence:

> I think you prefer to be _____ into intimacy rather than me being all over you.

The context is that my partner once told me about the 10-90 kissing rule which says:

> "The secret to a kiss is to go 90% of the way, and then hold… Hold for as long as it takes, for her to come the other 10"

So I'm trying to validate her and say that I'll initiate any intimacy but I absolutely respect you and wait for you to give a green light. I'm looking for verb with a very **positive connotation** and **reassuring**.

I tried:

- persuaded
- convinced
- eased into

and all of them sound terrible to me. Also, any alternative phrasing is more than welcome.

Comment: I think you prefer to *participate*. Your construct may set up an unwanted passive sense.

Comment: Is it essential for your purposes that a **single** word be found that **by itself** conveys precisely this meaning, or is it OK for the idea to be expresses by a phrase of, say, four or five words? There are probably many ways of accomplishing the latter, but it is doubtful whether the first is possible. Either way, it will help the potential answerers if you make that explicit in the question.

Comment: The syntax of the sentence into which the word is to be inserted, after the recent edit (unlike the syntax of original version) makes *eased* a very natural answer, so you need to explain why you think that it would 'sound terrible'.

Comment: The proximate cause of your challenge may lie in a partner complaining when you overwhelm, then instructing you to contribute 90%. She gets to participate barely, which she says she wants, and doesn't want. That's not a partnership. Now you're supposed to accommodate a skewed balance that she requires. The issue is not language.

Comment: @jsw29, I welcome any alternative suggestions. Question updated.

Comment: If you tagged your question with phrasal-requests too, I would suggest _You prefer to **have a say in** this_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try "[invited](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invite)" in your example sentence. Note the synonymous usage of the word "welcome" in the definition. It implies that you're making intimacy readily available (*positive* and *reassuring*), but that the invitation awaits her response (respectfully waiting for the green light). She is being "asked to" in the sense of a hopeful request for her to attend, without any sense of requirement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: **invited** sounds the least intrusive way of saying it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try rephrasing into a simpler sentence with a romantic connotation.

Try something like:

*I will always kiss an outstretched hand*

This reflects how you will always respect her wishes to be or not be intimate by waiting for her to give you a sign, but you also will be the intimate one in the situation.

This may be a bit too flowery for what you need, I apologize